# How do I reference a list then auto-generate numbers to form item identification tags in Google sheets or Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I am creating an item inventory and want to make a function that auto-generates item identification tag numbers for my items. I have two sheets. Sheet 1 contains the list of items and what category they belong to. Sheet two contains cells that define how the identification tags should be named. I need a function that does the following: =If(A2="Camera", "CAM-[auto generated number]") If(A2="Sound", "SOUND-[auto generated number]") and so on. I have provided an example below.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fhHs.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgzEb.png)

Comment: Where is the example? How should the desired output look?

Comment: In Sheet1 (above) under "Equipment Code"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=if(a2="Camera","Cam-"&randbetween(200,299),if(a2="Sound","Snd-"&randbetween(300,399),"Error"))
```

But you may end up with numbers used twice - controlling numbers used is more interesting.

Written on a smartphone so not tested, now tested and works.

Comment: I would like the ability to reference the list created in Sheet 2 to come up with the names (for example [Cameras=CAM-xxxx]). Is there a way to reference that list in Sheet 2?

Comment: You can get information from another sheet with indirect() but from a list with vlookup() or with index() and match(). There are many many q&a on here about vlookup and index with match.